Almost Projection open map
Consider the map $g:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, defined by
$$
g(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\overline{0},\qquad\quad \text{ if }x=\vec{0},\\
y^{\perp_x},\qquad \text{ if }x\neq\vec 0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $y^{\perp_x}$ is the orthogonal projection of $y$ over the line spanned by $x$.
Explicitely, for $x\neq0$, $g$ assumes the form
$$
g(x_1,x_2;y_1,y_2):=\left(y_1-\frac{x_1y_1+x_2y_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}x_1,y_2-\frac{x_1y_1+x_2y_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}x_2\right).
$$
Is the map $g$ an open map?

I am afraid that the map is not open, at least for neighborhood of the origin. Indeed, take any $\tilde y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider $B_0(R_1)\times B_{\tilde y}(R_2)$ as open neighborhood of $(0,\tilde y)$, for some $R_1,R_2>0$. Then $0=g(0,y)$, for any $y\in B_{\tilde y}(R_2)$, but $0$ has no open neighborhood contained in $g(B_0(R_1)\times B_{\tilde y}(R_2))$. More precisely, we state the following
Claim: for sufficiently small $\lambda$,
$$
g(B_0(R_1)\times B_{\tilde y}(R_2))\cap \langle\tilde y\rangle\cap B_0(\lambda)=\emptyset.
$$
Indeed, since for fixed $x$, $g(x,y)\in \langle x^\perp\rangle$, we have that $$
g(B_0(R_1)\times B_{\tilde y}(R_2))\cap\langle\tilde y\rangle=g(\{\tilde x\}\times B_{\tilde y}(R_2)), 
$$
for any $\tilde{x}\in B_0(R_1)$ such that $\tilde x^\perp\in\langle\tilde y\rangle$. So, take such a $\tilde x$, then
$$
g(\{\tilde{x}\}\times B_{\tilde y}(R_2))=B_{\tilde y}(R_2)\cap\langle\tilde y\rangle,
$$
thus, to prove the claim, it is enough to choose $\lambda<\|\tilde y\|-R_2$.
By the way, I am confident that the map $g:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is open.
